# Content URI passed in EXTRA_STREAM appears to "To:" email field

Tags: android, email, android-fileprovider

I am creating a file in the cache directory that I'd like to share with others (via Gmail / WhatsApp etc).  I am able to do this using FileProvider, and it works OK for WhatsApp.  When choosing to share on Gmail the photo is correctly attached, but the Uri that I pass via Intent.EXTRA_STREAM also ends up being parsed by Gmail as an address in the "To:" field of the newly composed email, along with the address(es) that I pass via Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL.

So the user is required to delete the bogus (Uri) email address before sending.  Any idea how to prevent this from happening?

```
Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), "com.mypackage.fileprovider", cacheFile);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image/jpeg");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"some_address@gmail.com"});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Photo");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Check out this photo");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);

if(intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null)
{
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.share_file)));
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Replace:

```
intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image/jpeg");
```

with:

```
intent.setType("image/jpeg");
```

Your problem is not `EXTRA_STREAM`, but rather that you are putting the `Uri` in the `Intent`'s data facet.

Also, if your `minSdkVersion` is below 21, you will need to take [some extra steps to ensure that clients can read the content](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/31/granting-permissions-uri-intent-extra.html), as the `Intent` flag is not applied to `EXTRA_STREAM` automatically on earlier versions of Android.

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed it.  Huge respect for the speed of your answer.  Have spent a couple of hours searching around for a solution to no avail.  Would vote you up if only I could....

Comment: You just got to love SO. Android behaves so strange sometimes - we'd all be damned without this platform and people like you.